# Is it possible to invoke Words function "Compare..." from Office JS API?

Tags: office-js, office-addins, word-addins

Is there a way to invoke Word.Document.Compare method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.compare) from Office JS API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible at this time with the Office JavaScript APIs. Consider suggesting it at [Office Developer User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).